# Finding resulting points using boost rtree in a geometry

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, c++14, boost-geometry

I'm trying to use `boost::geometry`'s rtree DS on one of my project, but I'm finding it difficult to navigate through the docs. Certain methods are poorly documented and I couldn't find sufficient examples. Now I'm trying to build a sample program so I could build it further.

So, in the below example I've a rtree of points and a box, and I need to find all points that lie inside that box. Another thing I would like to ask is, I couldn't find `packing algorithm` constructor or method, so how to use that as well. Here's what I've done till now -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>


namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;


struct my_point
{
    float x, y;
    my_point(float _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

struct my_box
{
    my_point ll, ur;
    my_box(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) : ll(x1,y1), ur(x2,y2) {}
};

// Register the point type
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(my_point, float, cs::cartesian, x, y)

// Register the box type, also notifying that it is based on "my_point"
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(my_box, my_point, ll, ur)



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<my_point, int>> pts;
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(2,2), 5));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(3,3), 1));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(4,5), 3));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(4,4), 12));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(1,2), 50));
    // ....

    bgi::rtree<std::pair<my_point, int>, bgi::dynamic_rstar> rT(bgi::dynamic_rstar(pts.size()));
    rT.insert(pts.begin(), pts.end());

    my_box box1(1,1,4,4);
    // how to retrieve all points or their .second inside this box?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Packing algorithm is used if you pass a range into the constructor of the R-tree:

- [rtree(Iterator, Iterator)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/rtree_iterator__iterator_.html)
- [rtree(Range)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/rtree_range_const___.html)

Retrieving values from the R-tree can be done with `query` method or query iterators:

- [R-tree queries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/queries.html)
- [query(Predicates, OutputIterator)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/query_predicates_const____outiter_.html)

See also this [R-tree Quick Start example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/rtree_quickstart.html).

One final remark. In your code you pass the number of points into the `bgi::dynamic_rstar`. The argument of `bgi::dynamic_rstar` is not the number of contained values. It is the max number of values stored in a single node of the R-tree (corresponding to page size of persistent/disk-based R-tree). So if you pass `bgi::dynamic_rstar(pts.size())` the R-tree contains only one node containing all of the points which means that there is no hierarchy of nodes, no spatial partitioning and effectively the rtree behaves like a vector. Instead use e.g. `bgi::rstar<4>` or some greater number if values overlap is big, but in your case it shouldn't since you're storing points. This would be enough:

```
bgi::rtree<std::pair<my_point, int>, bgi::rstar<4> > rT(pts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `query` method on your rtree and pass an appropriate query strategy eg -

```
std::vector<std::pair<my_point, int>> result;
rT.query(bgi::covered_by(box1), std::back_inserter(result));
```

For packing algorithm, although I'm not sure but this should work -

```
bgi::rtree<std::pair<my_point, int>, bgi::dynamic_rstar> rT(pts, bgi::dynamic_rstar(pts.size()));
```

However, I would suggest to verify it against documentation. Here's the full program I tested locally on my machine -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>


namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;


struct my_point
{
    float x, y;
    my_point(float _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

struct my_box
{
    my_point ll, ur;
    my_box(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) : ll(x1,y1), ur(x2,y2) {}
};

// Register the point type
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(my_point, float, cs::cartesian, x, y)

// Register the box type, also notifying that it is based on "my_point"
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(my_box, my_point, ll, ur)



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<my_point, int>> pts;
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(2,2), 5));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(3,3), 1));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(4,5), 3));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(4,4), 12));
    pts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(my_point(1,2), 50));
    // ....

    bgi::rtree<std::pair<my_point, int>, bgi::dynamic_rstar> rT(pts, bgi::dynamic_rstar(pts.size()));

    my_box box1(1,1,4,4);
    std::vector<std::pair<my_point, int>> result;
    rT.query(bgi::covered_by(box1), std::back_inserter(result));
    for(const auto &r: result){
        std::cout << r.second << ' ' << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```